# Windows 7 Pro x32 не видит в сети Windows 7 HP x64

Tags: сеть, windows-7

Доброго времени суток, коллеги. Ситуация в следующем. В сети 6 ПК - 1 Win 7 Pro x32, 1 Win XP Pro x32, 4 Win 7 HP x64. В сетевом окружении ПК с Win XP x 32 и Win 7 HP x64 видят все ПК в сети. Win 7 Pro x32 видит только себя и Win XP x32. С чем это может быть связано и как их подружить. Опять же идёт речь только с отображением в сетевом окружении, т.к. по сути доступ есть, т.е. на Win 7 Pro x32 не видно 4 ПК с Win HP x64, но при выполнении Win+R+'\%Имя ПК%' заходит на ПК в сети. Если требуется дополнительная информация, то я всё предоставлю. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: глупый вопрос: все ПК в одной группе?

Comment: Естественно. И в одной подсетке и с одинаковыми настройками. И брэндмауер вырублен, UAC вырублен, дополнительные параметры общего доступа настроены верно.

Answer (score 1):

Проверь службу доступа к файлам и принтерам в свойствах сетевого подключения. Она должна быть включена!Еще как вариант введи в командной строке win7x64 NET config server /hidden:no

Answer (score 0):

Проверь фаервол и антивирус.

Answer (score 0):

Кто является контроллером рабочей группы?На этом пк необходимо посмотреть пароль (скорее всего он таки есть), на втором пк необходимо при подключении рабочей группе нужно указать что группа уже создана, и эта машина только подключается к ней, и указать пароль.